# Erro ao deletar diretório(arquivo sendo usado)

Tags: c#

Estou compactando uma pasta e, após isso deletando a pasta que já existia.
O problema é que, em algumas situações, caio em uma exceção informando que um arquivo da pasta ainda está sendo utilizado:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sDiretorioZip, string.Concat(sDiretorioZip, ".zip"), CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sDiretorioZip);
Directory.Delete(sDiretorioZip, true);
```

Comment: Tentou dar uma `Thread.Sleep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione um `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int32);` antes de deletar o arquivo. O que acontece é que as vezes a pasta que está sendo comprimida não teve tempo de ser fechada pelo `ZipFile`, logo, o aplicativo irá retornar uma exceção de pasta em uso, impossibilitando sua exclusão. Ao adicionar o método descrito no inicio da resposta o seu aplicativo irá 'dormir' pelo tempo desejado (em milissegundos) que é exatamente o tempo necessário pro `ZipFile` terminar o seu serviço e a exclusão continuar normalmente. Observe:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sDiretorioZip, string.Concat(sDiretorioZip, ".zip"), CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sDiretorioZip);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
Directory.Delete(sDiretorioZip, true);
```

---

@EDIT: Como pedido, um código que exclua apenas quando a compressão está finalizada.

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sDiretorioZip, string.Concat(sDiretorioZip, ".zip"), CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sDiretorioZip);
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); //Um timing opcional pra não utilizar tanto da máquina
    try
    {
        Directory.Delete(sDiretorioZip, true); //Tentativa de exclusão, se o arquivo estiver em uso ele irá retornar uma exceção e o código irá se digirir ao bloco catch(){}
        break; //Sai do loop infinito após a exclusão do arquivo não retornar erro
    }
    catch (IOException err)
    {
        //Se der uma exceção, arquivo em uso por exemplo, ele tenta excluir novamente, até conseguir.
        continue;
    }
}
//Continuação do seu código
```

Comment: Eu tentei. Desculpe, deveria ter dito isso. 
Passei inclusive exatamente o mesmo tempo.
Você sabe se há uma forma de verificar se a compactação terminou?

Comment: Eu procurei na documentação e não achei nada relacionado ao término da compactação, mas tem como saber isso de uma forma meio 'gambiarra', mas é funcional, editei o tópico, teste por favor.

Comment: Então...fiz de outra forma, para tentar não fazer gambiarra.
O problema é que ainda da o erro de que o arquivo está sendo usado. Mesmo após o Dispose

Answer (score 0):

Segue o novo código, a[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]inda dando o erro, mesmo após o dispose...